Who are the "people of Israel" in Ezekiel 4?
2 Kings 17.1-6 says:

In the twelfth year of Ahaz king of Judah, Hoshea son of Elah became king of Israel in Samaria, and he reigned nine years. 2 He did evil in the eyes of the Lord, but not like the kings of Israel who preceded him....
In the ninth year of Hoshea, the king of Assyria captured Samaria and
deported the Israelites to Assyria. He settled them in Halah, in Gozan
on the Habor River and in the towns of the Medes.

2 Kings 17.24-29 says:

24 The king of Assyria brought people from Babylon, Kuthah, Avva,
Hamath and Sepharvaim and settled them in the towns of Samaria to
replace the Israelites. They took over Samaria and lived in its towns.
25 When they first lived there, they did not worship the Lord; so he
sent lions among them and they killed some of the people. 26 It was
reported to the king of Assyria: “The people you deported and
resettled in the towns of Samaria do not know what the god of that
country requires. He has sent lions among them, which are killing them
off, because the people do not know what he requires.”
27 Then the king of Assyria gave this order: “Have one of the priests
you took captive from Samaria go back to live there and teach the
people what the god of the land requires.” 28 So one of the priests
who had been exiled from Samaria came to live in Bethel and taught
them how to worship the Lord.
29 Nevertheless, each national group made its own gods in the several
towns where they settled, and set them up in the shrines the people of
Samaria had made at the high places....
They worshiped the Lord, but they also served their own gods in accordance with the customs of the nations from which they had been brought. 34 To this day they persist in their former practices. They neither worship the Lord nor adhere to the decrees and regulations, the laws and commands that the Lord gave the descendants of Jacob, whom he named Israel.

2 Kings 18.9 says:

9 In King Hezekiah’s fourth year, which was the seventh year of Hoshea
son of Elah king of Israel, Shalmaneser king of Assyria marched
against Samaria and laid siege to it. 10 At the end of three years the
Assyrians took it. So Samaria was captured in Hezekiah’s sixth year,
which was the ninth year of Hoshea king of Israel. 11 The king of
Assyria deported Israel to Assyria and settled them in Halah, in Gozan
on the Habor River and in towns of the Medes. 12 This happened because
they had not obeyed the Lord their God, but had violated his
covenant—all that Moses the servant of the Lord commanded. They
neither listened to the commands nor carried them out.

Ezekiel 1.2-3 refers to the later Babylonian exile:

On the fifth of the month—it was the fifth year of the exile of King
Jehoiachin— the word of the Lord came to Ezekiel the priest, the son
of Buzi, by the Kebar River in the land of the Babylonians. There the
hand of the Lord was on him.

Ezekiel 4.4-5 says:

Then lie on your left side and put the sin of the people of Israel
upon yourself. You are to bear their sin for the number of days you
lie on your side. 5 I have assigned you the same number of days as the
years of their sin. So for 390 days you will bear the sin of the
people of Israel.

Ezekiel 4.6-8 says:

After you have finished this, lie down again, this time on your right
side, and bear the sin of the people of Judah. I have assigned you 40
days, a day for each year. Turn your face toward the siege of
Jerusalem and with bared arm prophesy against her. I will tie you up
with ropes so that you cannot turn from one side to the other until
you have finished the days of your siege.

Who are the "people of Israel" in Ezekiel 4? Are they the people in 2 Kings 17.6 resettled in Halah, in Gozan on the Habor River and in the towns of the Medes? Or are they the people in 2 Kings 17.24 from Babylon, Kuthah, Avva, Hamath and Sepharvaim and settled them in the towns of Samaria to replace the Israelites? Are they another people?
To add: why is the exile from Samaria in 2 Kings repeated differently twice?

I suggest that the sin of Israel and Judah is the historical sin, not just the contemporary sin, so that "Israel" need not be referring to any specific contemoraries.

Dan Fefferman answers the main question well. In response to the bonus question at the end:
The books of Kings throughout tell the history of the Northern and Southern kingdoms in parallel. For example, chapter 15 first tells us about the reign of Azariah in Judah, then about the five (!) kings that came to the throne in Israel during his reign, before returning to Judah. Chapter 16 tells us about the rule of Ahaz in Judah, then chapter 17 returns to the northern kingdom and recounts the history of Hoshea, the end of the northern kingdom, and the exile from Samaria. The history of the southern kingdom continues from chapter 18, and the account of the exile of the northern kingdom is recounted briefly to place it in the context of the southern kingdom's history - Hezekiah came to the throne in the third year of Hoshea, in his sixth year the Assyrians took Samaria and ended the northern kingdom, and eight years later they came to Judah.
The other answer suggests that chapters 17 and 18 recount two different deportations, but it's clear from comparing the dates that this is not the case. Both took place in the ninth year of Hoshea after a three-year siege.

I'm still not entirely sure that there was only one deportation even though I admit that Tiglath-Pileser could not have been involved during the year in question. Consider this footnote in the NABRE - On the other
17:5 "The king of Assyria" Shalmaneser was succeeded by Sargon II, who usurped the Assyrian throne in 722/721 B.C. In his inscriptions, Sargon claims to have captured Samaria during the first year of his reign.  It may be the the deportations were begun under Shalmaneser and finished under Sargon.

@DanFefferman while it's pretty clear that these two texts describe the same event, I do agree that it's quite plausible that there were multiple stages of deportation. We see three waves of deportation from Judah several years apart, for comparison.

The "people of Israel" in Ezekiel are the people of the northern kingdom of Israel, which had been destroyed by the Assyrians. They are not limited to those who were exiled to Assyria.  Many fled to Judah (2 Chronicles 30) and many more were probably not exiled at all.
The archaeological record suggests that most of the northern population actually remained in Israel. This also makes sense logically, since the majority of people lived in the countryside as subsistence farmers and herders and posed little threat to the Assyrian occupation. The Assyrians would want to remove the royal court, administrators, priests, military classes and others wealthy or powerful enough to pose significant resistance, but rather than the entire population. So we may conclude that Ezekiel referred to the whole nation of Israel rather than only those who had been exiles to area of the Habor River and the towns of the Medes.
The reason for two different accounts of deportations in 2 Kings is that deportations occurred under two or three kings. The ones reported in the OP are (first) the one under Tiglath-Pileser III c. 732 BCE, and (second) the one by Shalmaneser and possibly Sargon II a few years later.

CORRECTION - After considering user111403's comment and post, I realize that any deportations are described as occurring during the 9th year of Hoshea. This rules out Tiglath-Pileser III. However it is still possible that there were two or more waves of deportation, one under Shalmaneser and another under his son Sargon, who claims credit for them in his own inscriptions.

Thank you. The same would have occurred when the Romans removed the royal court, administrators, priests, military classes and others wealthy or powerful enough to pose significant resistance. We know this because in the Jewish revolt against Heraclius in Palaestina starting in 613AD, the Jews raised an army of 20,000 Jewish men. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_revolt_against_Heraclius

I have to disagree regarding the last paragraph. Chapters 17 and 18 both refer to the 9th year of Hoshea. This is a single event. +1 for the rest of the answer.

@user111403... I stand corrected regarding the 9th yr of Hoshea.
